How to connect Oracle Analytics Semantic Modeller to an Azure DevOps repository
I have been trying to store a semantic model I created within the Oracle Analytics Cloud's Semantic Modeller in an Azure DevOps git repository. This should be possible since Azure DevOps is explicitely mentioned in the documentation as possible storage location.
It should have been as simple as entering the link to that repo's clone-URL into OAC's input mask and then login via the usual means (which works fine when connecting to GitHub), but the problem here is that the URL of DevOps is strangely formed.

The URL lacks the common .git-suffix and pasting it into OAC just gives an error that it is the wrong format. I have tried both HTTPS and SSH for this.
I have also tried, just to be certain, to manually add the .git at the end of the URL, and while this did allow me to go to the next step, finalizing the configuration and attempting a connection returned another error ("git-receive-pack: not found") which makes sense, of course. This isn't a case of the repo being on-prem (if that's even possible here) and requiring a VPN or proxy nor is it set to Private. If the URL didn't resolve at all, I'd haven gotten another error (something about URL being invalid; seen it earlier after missing the last letter during copy-pasting)
What am I missing here?
